# context menu, strange constraint warning in console swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui, contextmenu

I have create a simple list in swiftUI in order to try the context menu

```
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        List {
            ForEach(self.dm.storage) { airportData in
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    ZStack{

                        Text("Hello list")
                    }.contextMenu {
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I run the code on the simulator I get this warning from swiftUI.

[image: console warning]

any reason why, how can I solve this issue?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a SwiftUI Bug you don't have to worry about. Similar warnings appear if you use a Toogle for example.
This doesn't affect your App and can be ignored (also its annoying to see warnings in the console).

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed as of Xcode beta `12.0`. This was confirmed by a response today, to my feedback radar sent on April 1st. I then tested it and it all works perfectly now.

No more strange warnings!